# Список глаголов типа «привыкнуть – привык»

Tags: грамматика, глаголы

Есть глаголы с суффиксом *-ну-*, которые образуют прошедшее время c утратой суффикса *-ну-* и без добавления суффикса *-л*:

> замёрзнуть – замёрз, погибнуть – погиб,

в то время как другие сохраняют суффикс *-ну* и добавляют суффикс *-л*:

> глотнуть – глотнул, махнуть – махнул.

Вот есть статья об этом: [Н. А. Еськова, Устройство парадигм глаголов
непродуктивного класса с инфинитивом на -нуть](http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200101507).

Всего глаголы типа «погибнуть – погиб» образуются от 60 корней, и в этой статье дается список тех из них, которые могут употребляться без приставки, но есть и такие, типа «привыкнуть – привык», которые без приставки не употребляются. Где можно найти список этих последних глаголов, глаголов, которые всегда употребляются с приставками, но образуют прошедшее время c утратой суффикса *-ну-* и без добавления суффикса *-л*? Работы Еськовой, которые она упоминает в библиографии к своей статье, мне найти не удалось.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Гугл по запросу *«бегнуть вергнуть двигнуть»* находит статью [Н.Слюсарь 2012](http://www.slioussar.ru/resources/VerbDatabase/SlioussarVerbs.pdf) co списком всех 60 известных корней этого класса:

> (НУ)-класс
>   60 глаголов: *–бегнуть*, крепнуть, блёкнуть, липнуть, брюзгнуть, мёрзнуть, бухнуть, меркнуть, *–вергнуть*, мокнуть, виснуть, молкнуть, волгнуть, мякнуть, *воскреснуть*, *набрякнуть*, *–выкнуть,* никнуть, вязнуть, *обрыднуть*, вянуть, пахнуть, гаснуть, *промозгнуть*, гибнуть, пухнуть, глохнуть, *разверзнуть*, горкнуть, сипнуть, грузнуть, склизнуть, грязнуть, слабнуть, *–двигнуть*, слепнуть, дохнуть, слизнуть, дрогнуть, сохнуть, дрыхнуть, *–стигнуть*, дрябнуть, стынуть, дряхнуть, сякнуть, жолкнуть, терпнуть, жухнуть, тихнуть, *заскорузнуть*, *–торгнуть*, *захряснуть*, тускнуть, зябнуть, тухнуть, *исчезнуть*, хрипнуть, киснуть, чахнуть

Корней, требующих приставки, в списке всего 14. Еще несколько бесприставочных глаголов, отсутствующих в таблице у Еськовой, например «брюзгнуть».

Comment: То, что нужно! Огромное вам спасибо!

Comment: Для тех, кому это интересно: у двух глаголов в этом списке, _вянуть_ и _стынуть_, корень оканчивается на гласный, эти глаголы в прошедшем времени могут не терять суффикс _-ну-_, но _-л_ тоже добавляют: _вянул/вял_, _стынул/стыл_. И вообще, многие из этих глаголов имеют параллельные формы прошедшего в ремени, с _-ну-_ и без этого суффикса.

Comment: так у них и параллельные формы  инфинитива имеются: _завять, застыть_ . Впрочем, и у других глаголов из списка тоже:  _достичь_, _погрязть_, _завязть_.